# function st_within(sde.st_geometry, geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgis, enterprise-geodatabase, st-geometry

If I run the following query in PostgreSQL 9.2 I get the geometry:

```
select st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((-123.13974380493164 49.258142464379425,-123.11695575714111 49.25450118750378,-123.11914443969727 49.24965507167121,-123.13845634460449 49.25158797259088,-123.14326286315918 49.254669252349466,-123.14257621765137 49.25595773048919,-123.13974380493164 49.258142464379425))')
from park
```

However, if I try to put the st_geomfromtext() into an st_within, like this:

```
select objectid
from park
where st_within(shape,st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((-123.13974380493164 49.258142464379425,-123.11695575714111 49.25450118750378,-123.11914443969727 49.24965507167121,-123.13845634460449 49.25158797259088,-123.14326286315918 49.254669252349466,-123.14257621765137 49.25595773048919,-123.13974380493164 49.258142464379425))'),4326) = 't'
```

I get:

> function st_within(sde.st_geometry, geometry, integer) does not exist...You might need to add explicit type casts

Looks like I need to cast my WKT as st_geometry somehow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes the error message actually describes the issue. You just need to reread it to see the mismatched datatypes.

Comment: Even solely within PostGIS, you've got a syntax error, as well -- the "4326" is the second parameter  of the `ST_GeomFromText` function, but you have it as the third parameter of ST_Within (paren alignment issue).  Change `))'),4326)` to `))',4326))`

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up PostGIS spatial columns and sde spatial columns. Your 'shape' column is using the Esri spatial type. Your ST_GeomFromText() function is creating a PostGIS spatial type. And the ST_Within() function is complaining that you're mixing types. Figure out what the Esri equivalent to ST_GeomFromText() is, and use that, so your types match.

Comment: I'm guessing it's sde.ST_GeomFromText

Comment: The comparison function also needs to be `sde.ST_Within` (so that the parameters match the function)

Comment: It SHOULD be sde.st_geomfromtext, but my PostegreSQL 9.2, PostGIS 2.0.6 does not have such a function, on st_geomfromtext().